# How to pass a variable to another page in php using GET or POST method?

Tags: php, mysql, forms

I am making an editing form.
There are 2 forms, one form called `edit1.php` and another form called `edit.php`.  This second one should get the id generated from the `edit1.php` and use it to generate further queries. The following is the code for the 2 files:

#### edit1.php:

```
<table>
  <tr>
    <td align="center"><h4><b>EDIT DATA</b></h4></td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table border="3">
      <form action="edit.php" method="get">
      <?php

      $vendors = "SELECT `vendor`.`v_id`,`vendor`.`v_name` FROM `stfood`.`vendor`";
      $result = mysqli_query($con, $vendors);

      while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){
        echo ("<tr><td>'".$row["v_id"]."'</td>");
        echo ("<td>'".$row["v_name"]."'</td>");
        echo ("<td><a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['v_id']."\">Edit</a></td></tr>");

      }

      ?>
      </form>
      </table>
```

#### edit.php:

```
<?php
require 'init.php';
require 'functions.php';

?>
<html>
<head>
<title>Form Edit Data</title>
</head>
<body>
<table border=1>
  <tr>
    <td align=center>Form Edit vendor Data</td>
  </tr>
  <tr>
    <td>
      <table>

      <?php
        echo $_REQUEST['v_id'];
      $vendor = "SELECT `vendor`.`v_name`, `vendor`.`v_email`,`vendor`.`v_desc`,`vendor`.`cont_id` FROM `stfood`.`vendor` WHERE `vendor`.`v_id` = '".$v_id."'";
      $vendor_result = mysqli_query($con, $vendor);
      $row = mysqli_fetch_array($vendor_result);
      ?>
      <form method="post" action="edit_data.php">
      <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $row["v_id"];?>">
        <tr>        
          <td>Name</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="name" size="20" value="<?php echo $row["v_name"]; ?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Email</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="email" size="50" value="<?php echo $row["v_email"];?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td>Vendor Description</td>
          <td>
            <input type="text" name="description" size="100" value="<?php echo $row["v_desc"];?>">
          </td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
          <td align="right">
            <input type="submit"
          name="submit value" value="Edit">
          </td>
        </tr>
      </form>
      </table>
    </td>
  </tr>
</table>
</body>
</html>
```

When I run the code, the first form displays all the relevant data, and when I click on the `edit` link the page gets redirected and I can see the `v_id` passed in the URL, but nothing comes into the `edit.php` file.  When I do a `var_dump($row['v_id']);` I get `NULL`.

Why is `v_id` not set in `edit.php`?

Comment: PHP is stateless and therefore you must use something like `SESSIONS` or a database to store this information and reference in your next application.

Comment: You never did `$v_id = $_REQUEST['v_id']` so there is no `$v_id` that you try and use in your query. `error_reporting(E_ALL);
ini_set('display_errors', '1');`

Comment: thanks. where can i place this? $v_id = $_REQUEST['v_id'] to make it work?

Answer (score 1):

Since your hyperlink looks like this:

```
<a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['v_id']."\">Edit</a>
```

Your edit.php should use

```
echo $_GET['id'];
// or something like this
$received_id = $_GET['id'];
// do validation whether you received a good id or not and then move on
...
...
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $received_id;?>">
```

Comment: Thanks a lot..Zedfoxus, it worked like a charm.. now my query is running perfectly...i have validated and will pass the variable to strip out any funny characters for injection.

Comment: @KBHATT Please accept his answer to help others understand that this question has been solved and hence, no more answers. Thank you :)

Answer (score 0):

Try  using `$_GET['id']` instead of `$_REQUEST['v_id']` on `edit.php`

[See example #1 here](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Also, have you defined the `$v_id` before using it in the query?

[Like this.](http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.get.php)

Answer (score 0):

on your `edit.php` page you have:

```
<a href=\"edit.php?id=".$row['v_id']."\">Edit</a>
```

now on your `edit1.php` you should first have a `isset()` and then as follow:

```
if(isset($_GET['id']){

$id = $_GET['id'];

//carry on blah3 ...
```

Answer (score 0):

In the edit1.php you have not used form elements. The value $row['v_Id'] should be the value of form element input like this inside form

```
<input type='hidden' name='v_I'd value ='<?php echo $row['v_id'] ?>'>
```